# Where can i find such javascript/jquery or htmlp5/css3 content grid/slider?

Tags: javascript, html, css

http://www.overseas.hr/  <--go there

Anyone knows where such slider/grid can be downloaded for free be it as a wordpress plugin or html file?

Comment: you make it yourself with jQuery, most of these sliders are custom made because that is the easiest way to implement it. (you want a different design, different height, maybe even different behavior. than you better build one yourself). Simple on click function should to the trick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is [one](http://www.designyourway.net/drb/slidedeck-jquery-slider/). There are many live demos you can check and pick whatever you want.